# what is involved it supporting Smart on FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I'm stuck while working on smart on FHR.  how I will be able to Authorize through my code, currently I'm testing my Authorization and sandbox using the Launch Button. here is an example
[ScreenShot](https://www.screencast.com/t/kPTw4h0KYDf)

I just want to know which values should I pass to authorize as I authorize clicking after Launch Button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The documentation on SMART app launches might be helpful for you: https://hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/app-launch.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the "iss" and "launch" parameters when the launch button is clicked. Please see the specification for more details. https://www.hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/app-launch.html